# AsyncStorage to store themeColor in React native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-context, asyncstorage

I am new in this topic (data store in asyncStorage) I want to store my theme color in asyncStorage because when user close the app them will remain same as they selected.
I am able to change the theme on click but there were some issue on click.

I have to click twice to change theme(eq. : if there is light theme then I have to click twick like light to dark and again light then I am able to get dark theme and If there is dark theme then I have to click twice to change theme like dark to light to dark then I will get light theme

This is my Context.js file

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Context = createContext();

export const TProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const toggleTheam = async () => {
    const DataClr = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Color');

    setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');

    AsyncData();
  };

  const AsyncData = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Color', theme);
  };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{theme, toggleTheam, setTheme}}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Context;
```

and this is my First.js file from where I change my theme on Press

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import Context from './Context';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const First = ({navigation}) => {
  const {theme, toggleTheam, setTheme} = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const Data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Color');
    if (Data) {
      setTheme(Data);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('Theme==>', theme);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: '100%',
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? '#fff' : '#000',
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          textAlign: 'center',
          color: theme === 'light' ? '#000' : '#fff',
        }}>
        First Screen
      </Text>
      <Button title="Change Color" onPress={toggleTheam} />
      <Button
        title="Go to next Screen"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Second');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default First;
```

I have tried to store my theme color in Context.js file but I am not able to get that theme when I refresh the app

Comment: In that console log returning the toggle theme? does it work? If not, can you share the storege function?

Comment: toggle theme log is working, but when i refresh the app the screen will remain same default theme

I have tried one thing let me share with you it is work but there were some issue here

 const toggleTheam = async () => {
    const DataClr = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Color');
    if (DataClr !== null) {
      if (DataClr === 'light') {
        setTheme('dark');
        console.log('Dark');
      } else {
        setTheme('light');
        console.log('Light');
      }
    } else {
      setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
    }

    AsyncData();
  };

Comment: here I am have to click twice o change the theme. like if it is light theme then I have to click twice to get dark theme and if it is dark theme I have to click twice to get light theme

Comment: this code is from First.js

 useEffect(async () => {
    const Data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Color');
    if (Data) {
      setTheme(Data);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('Theme==>', theme);

Comment: You can edit your own question que the required information.

Comment: yes bro I had change the quesion

Answer (score 0):

I have use this to solve this funcnality. and I am able to store `useContext` data in `asyncStorage`.

```
const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
const [clr, setCle] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const MainTheme = async () => {
    try {
      const storedTheme = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Color');
      if (storedTheme !== null) {
        setTheme(storedTheme);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  MainTheme();
}, []);

const toggleTheam = () => {
  setTheme(value => {
    const newTheme = value === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    SetData(newTheme);
    return newTheme;
  });
};

const SetData = async newTheme => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('Color', newTheme);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```